# EXCEL replace a #SPILL! error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, error-correction

I have a spill error in Excel, and I want to replace this with an NA.

I tried using IFERROR, but this hasn't worked.

Is there another way around this ?

[image]

[image]
[image]

The Helper tab uses a lookup table to direct OFFSET and INDEX formulas used throughout, it only starts at Jan 2020 which is where the SPILL comes from.

From the comments (Daniel B) it seems SPILL isn't an actual error, hence IFERROR not working, but is there another way I can replace SPILL ?

[image]

Here is what is shown in cell B6

[image]

Comment: From what I understand, `#SPILL!` doesn’t indicate an error with the formula execution but rather with where the results would go (blue dashed area in your screenshot).

Comment: I'm surprised at the first place that your original formula gives the #SPILL error, I don't expect it from INDEX & MATCH, could you please evaluate your formula and explain at which step SPLIT occurs and which are intermediate results before?

Comment: @DanielB i had thought that, but is there an IFSPILL equivalent of IFERROR ?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I've added some more detail to the question

Comment: OK, thanks. Please try to use `@O2`, hopefully that will solve it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász   'at'02 corrected itself to become 'at'INDEX, and it worked, do you want to add as answer and ill mark as correct, and thank you  (can't use more than one at sign in comments)

Comment: this is what worked: =IFERROR(@INDEX(Helper!$E$2:$E$25,MATCH(O3,Helper!$E$2:$E$25,0)-1),"NA")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Excel try to be too clever and fills down your formula creating an array formula.

This is a behaviour sometimes occurring in newer versions of Excel.

To clarify you want to use a single formula only, you can use `@` ([implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34))

so your formula will become: `...@INDEX(...`